# Config puma to use pdfkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, pdfkit

I'm trying change **unicorn** to **puma**, but i have a problem with **pdfkit**. To use pdf with unicorn i must start it with 3 workers, but if i do the same with puma, it stop at 55%.

This is my puma config.

```
# config/puma.rb
port 3000
threads 0, 16
workers 3
```

My logs at start:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[23551] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[23551] * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sassy Salamander
[23551] * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
[23551] * Environment: development
[23551] * Process workers: 4
[23551] * Preloading application
[23551] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[23551] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[23551] - Worker 0 (pid: 23571) booted, phase: 0
[23551] - Worker 1 (pid: 23580) booted, phase: 0
[23551] - Worker 2 (pid: 23589) booted, phase: 0
[23551] - Worker 3 (pid: 23598) booted, phase: 0
```

And log when i try to create pdf (It never finish).

```
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.7ms)
[=================================>                          ] 55%
```

Other thing that i must to say is that in my layout i'm using something like that (It's rendering the header and the footer vía request to the same app):

```
  - if request_from_pdfkit?
    %meta{:name => 'pdfkit-header_html', :content => pdf_header_url(:protocol => 'http', :codigo =>params[:title])}
    %meta{:name => 'pdfkit-footer_html', :content => pdf_footer_url(:protocol => 'http', :codigo =>params[:title])}
```

Thanks for help!

**edit:**
I did other try, i created 2 endpoints, 1 sleep the app a lot of time (**/sleeprequest**) and other render a basic json (**/examplerequest**).
I started with the same config, and if i do the **/seleeprequest**, the app is blocked and don't accept the **/examplerequest**.

I have a nginx before that with this basic conf (I don't know if it can be a problem):

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

And my processes

```
ps aux | grep puma
alejand+ 29391  2.1  1.2 573648 206572 pts/22  Sl+  10:18   0:07 puma 3.8.2 (tcp://localhost:3000)
alejand+ 29413  1.0  2.2 1193920 365412 pts/22 Sl+  10:18   0:03 puma: cluster worker 0: 29391
alejand+ 29422  0.5  1.9 1180024 313324 pts/22 Sl+  10:18   0:01 puma: cluster worker 1: 29391
alejand+ 29431  0.5  2.0 1180024 329728 pts/22 Sl+  10:18   0:02 puma: cluster worker 2: 29391
```

Comment: I don't think that the problem is related to application server. find error log of pdfkit in devlopment.log or production.log or puma.log and show us.

Comment: Pdfkit don't show errors, It try to render the views and for that i need 3 workers. 1 for the main request and other 2 for header and footer. With unicorn and 3 workers it's working. I think i'm doing something wrong with the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add below line in `config/application.rb` file:

```
 config.allow_concurrency = true
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found my error!

I had disabled the cocurrence in rails enviroment conf:

```
 config.allow_concurrency = true
```

Everything works fine!!. The problem was that i couldn't handle concurrent requests.